# Display error dialog (MessageBox) with Only "Close" or "Cancel" buttons?

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, dialog, design-guidelines

I read in [Windows Experience Guidelines: Error Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511267.aspx) that "OK" is an incorrect button to display on an error dialog.

> ...provide a Close button. **Don't use OK for error messages**, because this wording implies that problems are OK.

So, how can I display a simple error dialog with a single *Close/Cancel* button?

Is this possible with the standard [`MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.aspx) class or must I resort to custom dialog (or library) or other Win32 message / p-invoke "hacks"?

(There doesn't seem to be anything relevant in the [`MessageBoxButtons`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons.aspx) enumeration.)

Thanks.

Comment: If there's nothing in the `MessageBoxButtons` enum, this might be because you don't really need anything else. I clearly understand your point about an [OK] button, but it all depends on the ind of problem you've encountered. What else you want the user to anwer? He doesn't agree and wanna do something about this error? I don't think so. In my point of view, I would simply use the standard `MessageBox`, otherwise you'll have to implement your own, which shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: @WillMarcouiller But one *does* need something else, according to the *official* Microsoft design documentation linked :-) I believe it is targeted to Vista/Windows7, but the question still stands as MessageBox (and the underlying [MessageBox WinAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) does not provide this option: which simply means they not been "updated for the times". (And has nothing to do with "you don't really need anything else".)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the all-improved `TaskDialog`.

[Available from here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) with [description on usage here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787471%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

TaskDialog allows you to specify in more detail the buttons and icons that show and **is microsoft's own solution** to your problem in .Net.

-- update to answer @pst's comment

If you have to support Winows XP or earlier then there is a [very stable and reliable library on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/137552/WPF-TaskDialog-Wrapper-and-Emulator) which wraps and emulates the microsoft taskdialog class when you are using an earlier version of windows, and uses MS's own version if you are on Vista or later.

I have relied on this codeproject library approx 2 years ago, and it was stable then, so there should be no reliability issues at all.

Comment: Nice find. I wonder what would happen if running on Windows XP, though? (It makes it sounds like it uses a Vista/Windows7-only API.)

Comment: Then it is automatically going to be cancelled :)

Comment: Thanks for your input (and update). I did not even realize Vista/7 introduced a new TaskDialog API. Do you know of, of had experience with, issues (or performance concerns) when using these WPF dialogs in a WinForms application/host?

Comment: I've experienced no problems at all.  The TaskDialog class is pretty neat, allowing you to (for example) use a custom icon, custom buttons, or even more interesting stuff like radio buttons.  It all hangs together smoothly.  The only gotcha I ever noticed was that if you choose one of the default icons, it assumed you wanted some other behaviour - i think it was a default sound - (so choosing an error icon might play the windows default error noise) - but you could work around this by providing your own custom icon (which might look identical).